# Two dimensional array in Javascript with a certain cell size

Tags: javascript

I'd like to implement a 2 dim array with each cell having the same size because i need to draw it on a canvas. (e.g. 10 px)

How can I do that?

Thanks!

Code so far:

`Array[0][0] = myArray;`

Comment: What does the cell size have to do with the array?

Comment: you mean you want to draw a matrix?

Comment: It seems you're confusing a data structure with a visualisation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no two dimensional arrays in Javascript, so you have to use a jagged array, i.e. an array of arrays.

Initialise it using literal arrays:

```
var arr = [[ 1, 2, 3 ], [ 4, 5, 6 ]];
```

Or the Array constructor:

```
var arr = new Array(10);
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  arr[i] = new Array(10);
}
```

An array is not a visual element, so to display it you would loop through each outer and inner array, and draw something that represents each item.

Comment: I'd like to draw a matrix but with hidden lines